# Creating a model and its child in seeds.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models: `God` and `GodSkin`.

```
class God < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :god_skins
end

class GodSkin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :god
end
```

---

I'm trying to create some seed data, specifically a `God` record and many children `GodSkin` records.

```
God.create!(
    name: 'Agni',
    title: 'God of Fire',
    lore: 'There are few elements as destructive or as purifying as fire. Agni, God of Fire, is
           the embodiment of both of these qualities, with a head for each. Though the source of
           his origin warrants debate - for there are many tales of his parentage ranging from two
           simple sticks rubbed together, to the cosmic energy that made all things at the beginning
           of time - Agni is a pivotal and important God with many duties to the Pantheon. He is the
           twin brother to Indra, God of the Heavens and Rains and chief among warriors. Conversely,
           Agni is chief among priests, acting as messenger between mortals and Gods. Every Hindu ritual
           and prayer is performed in front of a fire of some kind, so Agni carries the words and sacrifices,
           traveling between the Earth and the Heavens. He is welcome in every home and every hearth and
           much beloved by the Faithful. Through his flames, Agni provides heat and light, but also cleanses
           impurities. Smoke from his pyres create the air and hold the Heavens aloft. The sun, a source of
           fire itself, brings life-giving energy to the world, and his lightning streaks the sky during storms.
           For all his kindness and service, Agni has two faces. One is the face of kindness and purity,
           turned towards the people and Gods. His other face, grim and resolute, guides the God of Fire,
           to play his role in the cosmic cycle of creation and destruction, to burn and blacken all the
           atrocities of the world to ash.',
    pros: 'High Single Target Damage',
    cons: 'Low Defense',
    tags: 'Melee,Tank',
    release_date: Date.parse('Oct 4, 2012'),
    god_skins: {
        god_skin: {
            name: 'test',
            url: 'http://www.google.com',
            price: '5000'
        },
        god_skin: {
            name: 'test2',
            url: 'http://www.google.com/asdas',
            price: '2300'
        }
    }
)
```

When running `rake db:seed` I'm getting an error `GodSkin expected, got an Array`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell your model that it is allowed to create its child by `accepts_nested_attributes_for :god_skins`. Then you only need to rename key from `god_skins` to `god_skins_attributes` and all should work.

Update:

One more change, instead of passing a hash with duplicate keys (!!!!!!) use array of hashes:

```
god_skins_attributes: [
    {
        name: 'test',
        url: 'http://www.google.com',
        price: '5000'
    },
    {
        name: 'test2',
        url: 'http://www.google.com/asdas',
        price: '2300'
    }
}
```

Another solution:

If for any reason you don't want to use nested attributes, you can create childs after parent has been created:

```
God.create!(
  name: 'Agni',
  title: 'God of Fire',
  ...
).god_skins.create!([
  {
    name: 'test',
    url: 'http://www.google.com',
    price: '5000'
  },
  god_skin: {
    name: 'test2',
    url: 'http://www.google.com/asdas',
    price: '2300'
  }
])
```

)

This however might create parent and then fail on creating childs, leaving you with parent with no child n your db. To prevent that you will need to wrap those calls in a transaction.